# Python to post and format API response data into Slack channel

Tags: python, json, flask, slack, slack-block-kit

Working on a script to present data in Slack channel.. I have a script I'm working on to request and return data that I need to post in the channel that gets invoked with a Slash command, but having an issue with presenting the data in the slack channel from where I've executed the Slash command.  I've been attempting to work with the Block Kit Builder, but I see no way of presenting that data coming back from my script using the template I created.

Then in the Block kit builder, I can kind of see the format I want and send it to Slack from the Block kit builder, but if I wanted my return response from my Python script to be formatted by the template and respond in the channel, it doesn't seem to work.. I'm thinking I'm definitely doing something wrong, but was looking for suggestions..

I've been searching on possibly how to do it in Flask, which is what I'm using to execute a Slash command in Slack to invoke my Python script to query the API, get the response and send it to Slack..

Thanx.

P.S. Stackflow won't allow me to post a snippet of the json and/or images.. yet... something about a '10 reputation'...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.  In my code, I reflected this:

```py
for i in pdjson:
    t = {}
    try:
        t["text"] = {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": f'{i["escalation_policy"]["summary"]} -  Layer: {i["escalation_level"]}'
        }
    except (KeyError):
        t["text"] = {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": f'{i["escalation_policy"]["summary"]} -  Layer: {i["escalation_level"]}'
        }
    t["value"] = i["user"]["summary"]
```

Now I can present in the slack workspace with the block kit template. Now I just have to figure out how make the 'value' show up once I select an item in the list.